# PayPal Express Checkout 'Amount Paid' not showing

Tags: magento-1.9, paypal-express

I have **PayPal Express Checkout** activated as a payment method on my store. When a customer orders I receive the money via PayPal and the order is stored in Magento, however the 'amount paid' shows as 0.00.

Is there a setting I am missing to get the payment amount to show?

Comment: What is the status of the order in magento?

Comment: It is 'processing'.

Comment: Can you please add a screenshot of the order view page after masking the customer and creditcard or payment related info?